# Filling out text box after navigating to it using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I've managed to write a program that can navigate to the desired website, and click on the first textbox I want filled out. The problem i'm having is that the send_keys method i'm using is not filling out the desired textbox with 'Testing', and i'm receiving this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'
```

Here is the code so far:

```
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path_to_chromedriver')


def get_url(url):
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    Wait(driver, 30).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located
                           ((By.ID, 'signup-button'))).click()


def fill_data():
    sign_up = Wait(driver, 30).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located
                                     ((By.XPATH,
                                       '/html/body/onereg-app/div/onereg-form/div/div/form/section/section['
                                       '1]/onereg-alias-check/ '
                                       'fieldset/onereg-progress-meter/div[2]/div[2]/div/pos-input[1]'))).click()
    sign_up.send_keys('Testing')


get_url('https://www.mail.com/')
# Find the signup element
fill_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

find_elements_by_xpath` returns all matching elements, which is a list, so you need to loop through and get text attribute for each of the element

Also, in the fill data method you are trying to fill data for a signup form so you need to identify all elements on that form and process with the form your with your data.

Your xpath was incorrect while filling email Id, please update your xpath and try again

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
import time 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait



# Open Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path_to_chromedriver')


def get_url(url):
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()



def fill_data():

    Wait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable
                           ((By.ID, 'signup-button'))).click()

    inputBox = Wait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/onereg-app/div/onereg-form/div/div/form/section/section[1]/onereg-alias-check/fieldset/onereg-progress-meter/div[2]/div[2]/div/pos-input[1]/input")))
    inputBox.send_keys('Testing')


get_url('https://www.mail.com/')
# Find the signup element
fill_data()
```

Comment: @live for the hunt: please accept this answer and hit upvote button after your confirmation